# Is it safe to move .Renviron & .Rhistory into different directories?

Tags: r, installation

## Scenario

I read [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/running-rstudio-and-setting-up-your-working-directory-easy-r-programming) it was a good idea to make a working directory for R by making a new folder called "R" in the "Documents" folder, so I did exactly that: `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\R`.

When I installed R (v4.0.0) to my Windows 10 PC, it installed here: `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0`.

After installing and running R with RStudio, `.Renviron` and `.Rhistory` appeared here: `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents`.

There is a different `.Rhistory` in `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\R` that updates each time I use R (the files in `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents` have not updated themselves since installation day).

## Questions

Without rendering R and/or RStudio useless...

(1) can I move `.Renviron` from `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents` into `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\R`?

(2) can I move/delete `.Rhistory` (a possible unused copy) from `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents` since there appears to be another updated file by the same name in `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\R`?

If not, why not, and how can I clean up my `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents` directory?

Comment: If you read [`?Startup`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), it discusses where R searches for these files. Bottom line: current directory or under `$HOME` env-var. They can be overridden with env-vars `R_ENVIRON_USER` and `R_PROFILE`, respectively. (You will need to restart R/RStudio to see these changes ... if you don't see the changes, try logging out then login again, but I doubt that should be necessary.)

Comment: Right, ok, thanks. I checked out the documentation and it appears _"The name of the user file can be specified by the `R_ENVIRON_USER` environment variable; if this is unset, the files searched for are ‘`.Renviron`’ in the current or in the user's home directory (in that order)."_, which in my case seems to be: `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents`. I will look into changing my home directory to `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\R` or just delete/move them there (but I'm still worried this will make R crash if it needs either file).

Comment: From the [R for Windows FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#:~:text=You%20can%20find%20this%20from,find%20system%2Ddefined%20home%20directories.), R sets the home directory by first trying _"to use the Windows "personal" directory (typically C:\Users\username\Documents)"_, then if not present, _"${HOMEDRIVE}${HOMEPATH}"_ environment variables are used, and as a last resort _"the current working directory is used"_.

Comment: R *never* "requires" either or both files. If they don't exist, R happily continues. The only thing those files are *required* for is if you want or need startup routines/options/settings done when you start R. I have some options set and a custom package loaded on startup, but other than that very little is done. (Most defaults are sane for a reason :-). Bottom line, you only *need* them if there is material in there that you are unable (or it is inconvenient) to create manually each time you start R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to move/delete either file.

`.Renviron` only contained the text: `PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"`

`.Rhistory` contained all of the commands used up to the last time you issued a command (in my case, the up-to-date version in the working directory `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\R` contained all the commands used to download new R packages and some Rscript and the non-updated version in the `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents` folder contained only a single command used to download devtools).

I deleted `.Renviron` from `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents` and it did not reappear after restarting R/RStudio nor affect R/RStudio use.

I moved `.Rhistory` from `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents` into `C:\Users\jsmit\Documents\R` and in doing so replaced the old version there. It did not reappear after restarting R/RStudio nor affect R/RStudio use.